# Is it possible to style ProgressIndicator?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I like ProgressIndicator, except I'd like to change it's color and circle width. Is it possible (with css or without)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Of course, it's very easy.

You can find all related methods and styles in doc:

- API: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html?overview-summary.html
- CSS: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#progressindicator

  ```
  public class HelloProgressIndicator extends Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

      Pane root = new Pane();
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);

      ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(.314);
      // changing color with css
      pi.setStyle(" -fx-progress-color: red;");
      // changing size without css
      pi.setMinWidth(150);
      pi.setMinHeight(150);

      root.getChildren().add(pi);


      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
   }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS in JavaFX 19

```
.progress-indicator:indeterminate .segment {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```