# Customize ProgressIndicator of JavaFX 2.1

Tags: java, css, styles, javafx

How can I customize the ProgressIndicator from JavaFX 2.1? I tried to find some examples but couldn't find any? I want to change the color from blue default to black (but maintaing the gradient effect) and also to remove the "Done" text from when is finished.

I looked up at Javafx CSS reference guide but couldn't figure out how to style the substructure of an node. For the next example: ive tried

```
.progress-indicator .indicator { -fx-background-color: #000000; }
```

but doesn't seem to work. JavaFX css reference for ProgressIndicator

```
Style class: progress-indicator

The ProgressBar control has all the properties of Region and Node.

Substructure

indicator — Region
progress — Region
tick — Region
```

Comment: Partially.  [Is it possbile to style ProgressIndicator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11184255/682495)